# Get all items that do not exist in another table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am using `Laravel Framework 6.16.0` and I am having two tables, `logos` and `companies`:

**Logos:**

```
        Schema::create('logos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('companies_id')->default('999999');
            $table->string('logo_path')->nullable($value = true); // path to the logo image
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Companies:**

```
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('symbol'); // AAPL
            $table->string('name'); // company name such as Apple Inc.
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Models:**

```
class Logo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'logos';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'companies_id');
    }
}
```

```
class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'companies';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

I want to get all symbols that have no logo in the `logo-table` and the logo has not been updated for `90 days`.

I tried the following:

```
        $symbolsWithoutLogos = DB::table('companies')
            >leftJoin('logos', 'companies.id', '=', 'logos.companies_id')
            ->whereDate('logos.updated_at', Carbon::now()->subDays(90))
            ->whereNull('companies.logo_image')
            ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
            ->get('companies.*');
```

This query results in:

```
select `companies`.* from `companies` left join `logos` on `companies`.`id` = `logos`.`companies_id` where date(`logos`.`updated_at`) = ? order by `name` asc
```

However, I get not result when running this query, even when my companies table has enough records:

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I think you should correct the information you're giving us. Because first of all, I see the "logo_path" column and not the "logo_image" column as you write below in the builder. Secondly, in the raw Mysql query, I don't see "logo_image" or "logo_path". Finally, you talk about getting the "symbols" that don't have a logo but last updated the logo for at least 90 days ago, it's contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with Eloquent instead of using left join and DB facade.

I guess the relation between Company and Logo is 1:1 or 1:n. If we assume it is 1:1 then your query would look like this:

```
Company::whereHas('logo', function($query) {
    return $query->where('date', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(90));
})->orWhereDoesntHave('logo')->...
```

You should check: [Querying relationship absence](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

As long as we follow the Laravel naming convention we don't need to specify table name, Laravel will figure it out from the model name.

Logo model should be something like this:

```
class Logo extends Model
{
    // protected $table = 'logos'; 
    // not necessary, Laravel already knows to use logos table

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function company()
    {
        // return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'companies_id');
        // no need to specify foreign key if we follow naming convention
        // foreign key should be {foreign_model_singular}_id
        // in this case it is company_id
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
}
```

The Company model also does not require table name specified, it already knows it should be **companies**.

Company model:

```
class Company extends Model
{
    // protected $table = 'companies';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function logo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Logo::class);
    }
}
```

Please do check how $guarded and $fillable properties work. If only **id** is set as guarded, then all other properties are unguarded, not sure if this was your intention.

The full query should be:

```
Company::whereHas('logo', function($query) {
    return $query->where('updated_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(90));
})->orWhereDoesntHave('logo')
->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
->get();
```

Comment: Please see my updated question with the two models.

Answer (score 1):

->whereDate('logos.updated_at'
whereDate compare only date part of dateTime column ... try it with toDateString() from carbon ...

```
  $symbolsWithoutLogos = DB::table('companies')
            ->leftJoin('logos', 'companies.id', '=', 'logos.companies_id')
                ->whereDate('logos.updated_at', Carbon::now()->subDays(90)->toDateString())
                ->whereNull('companies.logo_image')
                ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->select('companies.*')
                ->get();
```